# cURL: IF Connection Times Out/Hangs, Restart Connection

Tags: linux, unix, curl

I need to restart a `cURL` connection after it has timed out/hung up for 2 minutes (120 seconds). I am on an Ubuntu system.

**Code So Far:**

```
/usr/bin/curl some.website -m 120 --retry 2 --retry-max-time 0
```

Is this code correct? I cannot use `wget` to complete this task.

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
curl -L -O -C - some.website
```

see :

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html (search : RESUMING FILE TRANSFERS)